# Get list of active dependencies and their versions during "cargo build"

Tags: build, dependencies, rust, rust-cargo

Some crates offer a pub `const &str`-version string, some do not. To have a general solution, I need a list of all dependencies and their versions as known to and used by `cargo build` during compilation so I can build my own `const &str` of *This is my own version and all the versions I was compiled with*-Debug output.

Is it possible to get a list of all dependencies and their version in `build.rs` ?

`Cargo.lock` seems to be a good source. Is it actually sound to parse `Cargo.lock` in `build.rs`? Is it guaranteed to have been updated to what Cargo actually uses and written to disk?

Comment: Maybe `cargo outdated` might be usefull?

Comment: The cargo lock file has all this information but I'm not sure at which point in the build process it is generated.

Comment: `Cargo.lock` would be a good source but is it actually sound to parse `Cargo.lock` in `build.rs`? Is it guaranteed to be up to date and written to disk before `build.rs` is run?

Comment: That's something I'm unsure of and wouldn't really want to rely on :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a crate for this: [build-info](https://crates.io/crates/build-info) ([lib.rs](https://lib.rs/crates/build-info), [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/build-info/latest/build_info/)).

It doesn't seem to be able to generate a `'static str` including dependency info on its own, but it does automatically parse `Cargo.lock` and include the relevant info into the final binary, with a similar effect.

#### Sample code (`build-info 0.0.32`)

This code is a little bit more complicated than you may need it to be, if you don't want to include recursive dependencies.

##### build.rs

```rust
fn main() {
    build_info_build::build_script().collect_dependencies(true);
}
```

##### main.rs

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

build_info::build_info!(fn build_info);

/// Collect all of the dependencies of this workspace into a single set.
fn get_dependencies() -> BTreeSet<(&'static str, &'static build_info::semver::Version)> {
    // called recursively on each of the dependencies in the tree
    fn visit(
        info: &'static build_info::CrateInfo,
        set: &mut BTreeSet<(&'static str, &'static build_info::semver::Version)>,
    ) {
        set.insert((&info.name, &info.version));
        for dep in &info.dependencies {
            visit(dep, set);
        }
    }
    let mut set = BTreeSet::new();
    let root_info = &build_info().crate_info;
    visit(root_info, &mut set);
    set
}

fn main() {
    for (name, version) in get_dependencies() {
        println!("{} {}", name, version);
    }
}
```

### Alternative Solutions

Check out [cargo-audit](https://github.com/RustSec/rustsec/tree/main/cargo-audit) and [cargo-auditable](https://github.com/rust-secure-code/cargo-auditable) for a security-oriented solution to the same problem, the former even works to some extent on programs that don't natively include this feature. Unfortunately, while `cargo audit bin` can be used to check for known security vulnerabilities in compiled Rust programs, I don't see any flags that print the list of libraries it recovers.